# My android app not running in other device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, out-of-memory, android-navigationview

My app is working on android10 but not in android7, but it was working in both before adding navigation view.

This is the error im getting

```
 Process: com.example.nemesis, PID: 7813
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nemesis/com.example.nemesis.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.nemesis.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:742)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
2022-01-09 23:32:42.283 7813-7813/com.example.nemesis E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:232)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:522)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:313)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:138)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.nemesis.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 132710412 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 26MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:624)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:457)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.createFromResourceStream(ResourcesImpl.java:1296)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:743)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:585)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:328)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:872)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:207)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
            ... 38 more
```

Comment: post your xml code too

Comment: share your gradle code

Comment: problem solved, it was my header, I used a large size background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have `OutOfMemoryError` error on that device:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 132710412 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 26MB until OOM
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:624)
```

Check if you use large drawable files in your XML layout, it may be that the device has low memory and couldn't load the images. Try to compress them, for example [convert images to WebP format](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp#convert_images_to_webp).